# Removing/comparing string value with a list - scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to remove members which exists in a string from a list consisting of those members.

Example:

String: `"ABC"`

List: `('A 'B 'C 'D)`

To do: Remove first element of string from the list

To remove the the element from the string:

I am converting it to a list using:

```
(car (string->list"ABC")
```

This gives me character list and first element: `#\A`

But I do not get how I can remove it from the list as both values do not compare: the character and list values.

Tried this weird approach which did not work:

```
((eq? (make-string 1 (car (string->list"ABC"))) (car (list 'A 'B 'C 'D))))
```

Does not work as string value does not compare with the first list value.

How I can compare & remove the first string alphabet from the original list??

Comment: Can you define list as (define lst '(#\a #\b #\c #\d)) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Error as list cannot have string element values:

This is not true. A list can have strings as well as characters as its elements, no problem. You're getting the error because you're using `car` on a string, not a list.

```
(car (list->string(list(car (string->list "ABC")))))
```

Ok, here you're calling `(string->list "ABC")` which gives you a list containing the character A, B and C. Now you're calling `car` on that and get the character A back. Up to here there's no problem.

But then you're calling `list` on that character getting a list which only contains the character A and then use `list-string` to turn this into the string `"A"`. This is still perfectly legal. But then you're calling `car` on the string `"A"` and that's the error because you're calling `car` on a string, but `car` only accepts a list (well, any pair actually) as its argument.

Since you're trying to compare A against that first element of `('A 'B 'C 'D)`, i.e. `'A`, which is a symbol, you probably want to convert the string `"A"` into the symbol `'A` (or the symbol `'A` into the string `"A"`). To do this, you can use the function `string->symbol` instead of `car`.

Once you have the symbol `A`, you can easily remove it from the list using the `filter` function:

```
(let ((a (string->symbol (list->string (list (car (string->list "ABC")))))))
  (filter (lambda (x) (not (eq? x a))) '(A B C)))
```

Comment: yup! thanks. just realised it when I ran it again now. changing it in the question. but my question still is how I can remove the first element of the string "ABC" from the list (A B C).

Comment: @jillika: Once you have the symbol, you can just use filter. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
(define lst '(#\a #\b #\c #\d))
(define str (string->list "abc"))

(define (reduce-list lst str)
  (cond
     [(empty? str) lst]
     [else (reduce-list (remove (first str) lst) (rest str))]
  )
)

(reduce-list lst str)
```

Result:

```
(list #\d)
```

Comment: I did try doing this. But I did not want to use a specific character list. That was the whole problem.